# Drupal aggregate css not working. All styles gone (no, it´s not a duplicate)

Tags: css, drupal, character-encoding, compression

I´ve read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480562/drupal-aggregate-css-not-working-all-styles-gone), that has an accepted solution, wich didn´t solved my problem, so, that´s why I´m opening a new issue, because I think they are related, but certainly not the same.

I´ve have a Drupal 7 installation.
I have an Omega Subtheme.
I´ve set "Rebuild theme registry on every page" ON.
When I try to enable css compression, the themes are gone. 
Not only my own subtheme is gone, but the administration theme is gone too (it´s the "seven" core theme).

To solve this I´ve tried:

> Saving all css files in UTF-8. To do that I´ve added this at the very
>   beginning of each scss file: `@charset "UTF-8";`. That line is before
>   everything, even the comments.

Then, I´ve followed each and every recommendation told [at this drupal post](http://drupal.org/node/986558):

**#12:** to comment these lines: `#Header append Content-Encoding gzip` and `#Header append Vary Accept-Encoding`.

**#15:** To add these lines in settings.php: `$conf['css_gzip_compression'] = FALSE;` and this one `$conf['js_gzip_compression'] = FALSE;`.

**#33:** To manually delete files/default/css and files/default/js folders.

I would like to add, as a sidenote, that I´ve tried the `@charset "UTF-8";` solution before, in my old shared host (I´ve a VPS now) in a Drupal 6 installation, and it worked.

I´ve run out of ideas, and just don´t know what I could try... any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the css files and adding them again (and clearing cache in the meantime) did the trick.